# Cannot connect to testlink using TestLinkAPI with Python3 - send_request() error with TestLink-API-Python-client-0.8.0

Tags: python-3.7, testlink

Trying to automate tests on TestLink via Python scripts, i downloaded TestLink-API-Python-client-0.8.0 and executed >>python TestLinkExample.py

and received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestLinkExample.py", line 114, in <module>
    myTLVersion = myTestLink.testLinkVersion()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkapigeneric.py", line 1296, in testLinkVersion
    tl_version = self.callServerWithPosArgs('testLinkVersion')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkapigeneric.py", line 1517, in callServerWithPosArgs
    response = self._callServer(methodNameAPI, argsOptional)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\testlink\testlinkapigeneric.py", line 1992, in _callServer
    response = getattr(self.server.tl, methodNameAPI)(argsAPI)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in single_request
    http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
TypeError: send_request() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

On some forums it was mentioned it is a bug in xmlrpc/client for Python3, but I could not find a fix for it.

Executing the same with Python2.7, got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestLinkExample.py", line 59, in <module>
    import testlink
ImportError: No module named testlink
```

TestLinkExample.py can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/testlink-api-python-client/files/latest/download).

Answer (score 0):

> Solved for me. 
>   Use the below command.

```
pip install --user xmlrpc
```